# Get list of files programmatically of android device on Windows 10

Tags: android, windows, windows-10, android-external-storage, unc

Below  is the image of how the android device automatically mounts on windows 10 (named: remdiz)
Actual Device: Redmi Note 5 Pro

[image: Device Mount]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOnI4.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOnI4.png

I am not able to get the list of files inside any given folder inside it because I see the path of it as `This PC\redmiz\disk\Music` which is not accessible in powershell, command prompt or even python.

[image]

**All I need is to list the files inside Music** as I have a same copy on my local and I want to find the difference
Accepted answer can be a batch file, windows command, powershell command, python script, command using git bash etc or any process that will give me a real path of the device named redmiz

Comment: MTP: Media Transfer Protocol.

Comment: Yes, after calming myself, did a research to find MTP doesn allow it. MTP Drive tool helped me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MTP doesnt allow this on Windows. Found a tool named MTPDrive. It was a little buggy, but helped by mounting the internal storage and external storage of Android as mapped drive leading to now limitless possibilites for my use case

Comment: Thank you for sharing. Did not know this tool but it works wonderfull. Thanks.